# How to send JSON and audio MP3 file using HttpClient POST in Java

Tags: java, httprequest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using `HttpClient` to send a request with **JSON** and **MP3 audio** content. Can anybody tell me where the below code goes wrong? I am using HttpClient version 4.5.2.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setUserAgent("MyAgent").setMaxConnPerRoute(4).build();
HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost("url");
httpPostRequest.addHeader("content-type","multipart/form-data");
File audioFile = new  File("filename.mp3");
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(audioFile);
StringBody jsonStringBody = new StringBody(gson.toJson(pojoObject).toString(), ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
multipartEntityBuilder.setContentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file", fileBody);
multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("jsonMetaData", jsonStringBody);
HttpEntity entity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
httpPostRequest.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPostRequest);
```